# Delete a record without using form in laravel

Tags: laravel

Need to delete a record without using form tag. Just pass a id in url and get a id need to process.

Thanks

Comment: Please add some additional info.

Answer (score 1):

follow below steps

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" thisRecordId="{{$id}}" id="btnDelete">Delete</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('a#btnDelete').on('click',function()
{   
    var thisElement = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: "{{url('/')}}" + '/deleteRecord/'+thisElement.attr('thisRecordId'),
        data : {'_token': '{!! csrf_token() !!}'},
        async: false,
        success:function(response)
        {
            console.log(response)
        }
    });
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('deleteRecord/{id}','YourController@deleteRecord');
```

**Controller**

```
public function deleteRecord($id)
{
    $findRecord = ModelName::findOrFail($id);
    $findRecord->delete();

    return 'success';
}
```

hope you will find your solution !

Answer (score -3):

Try like this

```
<a type="button" class="label label-danger" href="/user/delete/{{$user->id}}">Delete</a>
```

Controller method

```
public function getDelete($id)
{
 echo $id;
}
```

Comment: This is actually kind of "dangerous" because Laravel will not check for the CSRF token...

Comment: Very bad....anyone can delete it with this approach....you don't even have to be on the page you just type in the route in address bar and it's deleted

Comment: yes... you are right.. in that case we can check auth login n also user rights..  I just give a solution in short..